# Is it possible to find the number of elements in a circular doubly linked list?

Tags: list, algorithm, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

We have a circular doubly linked list with several elements. Every element has a link to the next element, a link to the previous element and a boolean value (true or false).
Four operations are defined for this list:

1. Get the value of the current element;
2. Reverse the value of the current element;
3. Move to the next element;
4. Move to the previous element;

How to find the number of list elements with such conditions? Is it possible?

The idea was to cast all elements to the same value, except one. Counting elements amount of such a list is not a problem, but how can I find out, that all elements are traversed?

Comment: Please show us your code. Then I can show you an implementation of counting your list.

Comment: And what does "Reverse the value of the current element;" mean? You need to show us your code and provide sample data in C# format that shows the operations.

Comment: The Tortoise and Hare algorithm can do it, but I don't remember how.

Comment: Enigmativity, there is no code for this question. "Reverse the value" is about "Every element has ... a boolean value (true or false)". Means "true" value becomes "false", and "false" value becomes "true".

Comment: Tortoise and Hare won't work for this. That algorithm is for finding a cycle when you have access to nodes.

Comment: @KasimKas - Please show us the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in O(N) time:

```
N=1
set current value = true
while(current value is true) {
   N = N*2
   set the next N values = false
   go back N elements to get back to the starting element
}
// Now we know that the whole list is false
set current value = true
scan forward until you get to true again, while counting
```

Comment: Clever. It sounds like the Counting may have been an XY problem, and your solution would correctly "cast all elements to the same value, except one" even if you skip the last step.